# How do I get my program to loop back and restart in Python?

Tags: python, loops

I understand this question has been asked before but I cant find a working solution. I'm new to Python and need to create a BMI calculator that will allow the user to enter multiple BMI's, but I can't get it to loop back to the beginning sucessfully. I've tried 2 ways and neither work.

Here's what I have for the first one, but this one wont run as "continue not in loop":
`

```
while True:
    print("BMI Calculator")

weight = float(input("\nPlease enter your weight in KG: "))
height = float(input("\nPlease enter your height in metres: "))
bmi = weight/(height*height)

if bmi <= 18.5:
    print("Your BMI is", bmi,"which means you are underweight.")

elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi < 25:
    print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are normal")

elif bmi > 25 and bmi < 30:
    print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are overweight")

elif bmi > 30:
    print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are obese")

else:
    print("There was an error with your input, Sorry.")

while True:
    answer = input("Would you like to enter another? key y/n: ")
    if answer in ("y", "n"):
        break
    print("Invalid Input")
if answer == "y":
    continue
else:
    input("\nPress the enter key to exit")
    break
```

`

The other one I have is this, but it prints BMI Calculator and then stops:
`

```
def start():
    print("\nBMI Calculator")

weight = float(input("\nPlease enter your weight in KG: "))
height = float(input("\nPlease enter your height in metres: "))
bmi = weight/(height*height)

if bmi <= 18.5:
            print("Your BMI is", bmi,"which means you are underweight.")

elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi < 25:
            print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are normal")

elif bmi > 25 and bmi < 30:
            print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are overweight")

elif bmi > 30:
            print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are obese")

else:
            print("There was an error with your input, Sorry.")

answer = input("Would you like to enter another? key y/n: ")
while answer == "y":
        start()
        answer = None

if answer == "n":
    input("\nPress the enter key to exit")
```

`

Comment: Is that actually what your code looks like or did the indentation get messed up?

Comment: You need to put all your code inside the loop, and break out when the user said so.

Comment: indentation messed up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem here is all about the indentation levels, Laura. Python knows that something is inside a block of code if the consecutive lines have all the same indentation(differently from C or Java, where blocks are delimited by opening and closing brackets).

Your code should look something like this:

```
while True:
    print("BMI Calculator")

    weight = float(input("\nPlease enter your weight in KG: "))
    height = float(input("\nPlease enter your height in metres: "))
    bmi = weight/(height*height)

    if bmi <= 18.5:
        print("Your BMI is", bmi,"which means you are underweight.")

    elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi < 25:
        print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are normal")

    elif bmi > 25 and bmi < 30:
        print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are overweight")

    elif bmi > 30:
        print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are obese")

    else:
        print("There was an error with your input, Sorry.")

    answer = input("Would you like to enter another? key y/n: ")

    if answer not in ("y", "n"):
        print("Invalid Input")
        break

    if answer == "y":
        continue
    else:
        input("\nPress the enter key to exit")
        break
```

In this snippet of code I have changed the boolean test and the instruction order from:

```
if answer in ("y", "n"):
    break
print("Invalid Input")
```

to

```
if answer not in ("y", "n"):
    print("Invalid Input")
    break
```

If you **break** from a loop, the following lines of code in that loop are not executed. Also, the comparison you were doing would always return `True` because the answer would be **in** ("y", "n"). I also removed the last loop because it makes more sense that way.

As for the second code, the only thing that function `start()` is doing, is `print("\nBMI Calculator")`, again because of indentation levels.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like in the second example you need to put the yes no question in the while loop. Something like this should work.

```
def start():
    print("\nBMI Calculator")

    while True:
        weight = float(input("\nPlease enter your weight in KG: "))
        height = float(input("\nPlease enter your height in metres: "))
        bmi = weight/(height*height)

        if bmi <= 18.5:
            print("Your BMI is", bmi,"which means you are underweight.")
        elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi < 25:
            print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are normal")
        elif bmi > 25 and bmi < 30:
            print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are overweight")
        elif bmi > 30:
            print("Your BMI is: ", bmi, "which means you are obese")
        else:
            print("There was an error with your input, Sorry.")
        answer = input("Would you like to enter another? key y/n: ")
        while answer == "y":
            start()
            answer = None
        if answer == "n":
            exit()

start()
```

I didn't put an else statement in the y/n question but that should be a simple fix, it looks like the statement you had written before would work fine.

Answer (score 0):

First Thing :

> you are facing issue causes of  indentation :

Second Thing :

For second function , I have some suggestion for you:

Instead of `print` use `return` there :

> The point of functions in general is to take in inputs and return
>   something. The return statement causes your function to exit and hand
>   back a value to its caller.

and use python `.format()` method

Here is your second code with some modification :

```
def start():
    print("\nBMI Calculator")
    weight = float(input("\nPlease enter your weight in KG: "))
    height = float(input("\nPlease enter your height in metres: "))
    bmi = weight/(height*height)
    if bmi <= 18.5:
        return "Your BMI is : {} which means you are underweight".format(bmi)
    elif bmi > 18.5 and bmi < 25:
        return "Your BMI is : {} which means you are normal".format(bmi)
    elif bmi > 25 and bmi < 30:
        return "Your BMI is : {} which means you are overweight".format(bmi)
    elif bmi > 30:
        return "Your BMI is : {} which means you are obese".format(bmi)
    else:
        return "There was an error with your input, Sorry."

print(start())

answer = input("Would you like to enter another? key y/n: ")
if answer == "y":
    start()
elif answer == "n":
    input("\nPress the enter key to exit")
```